# iPhone locationManager:didFailWithError problem when GPS disabled

Tags: iphone, mapkit, cllocationmanager

So, I've followed other related threads, but for some reason I'm still having this error and I'm about ready to tear my hair out.  I have implemented locationManager:didFailWithError to check and see if a user selects 'Don't Allow' to use the current location.

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"IN ERROR");
if ([error code] == kCLErrorDenied){  
 [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
 }
}
```

However, the following error always appears when the user selects 'Don't Allow'...it's strange, especially the order that the text 'IN ERROR' appears.

> ERROR,Time,293420691.000,Function,"void
>   CLClientHandleDaemonDataRegistration(__CLClient*,
>   const
>   CLDaemonCommToClientRegistration*,
>   const __CFDictionary*)",server did not
>   accept client registration 1
>   2010-04-19 21:44:51.000
>   testApp[1414:207] IN ERROR

So, it's outputting this error even before it has a chance to get into the didFailWithError function.  Does anyone have any ideas of what might be happening?  The rest of the locationManager code is as follows:

```
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer;
locationManager.distanceFilter = 2;  
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just an informational message from Core Location.  It's not crashing your app, the user will not see it and it does still call didFailWithError with the correct error code.

In my tests, the message appears on the iPhone simulator and device (3.1.3) and the iPad simulator but not the iPad device (3.2).

Comment: Thanks DyingCactus...I guess I'm just overly paranoid about Apple rejecting my app because of little things like that, but if it's normal, then I won't lose any more sleep over it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MapKit as well, this is an error in MapKit. MapKit is registering with Core Location, and then not properly handling the error reported when the user rejects the location update or it fails. It should pass this error on via a delegate method (as it does for geocoding errors), but doesn't.

Unfortunately I can't think of any way to intercept the message from core location, as MapKit maintains an instance of CLLocationManager which it uses to get the location, and that's the one which is reporting the error to its delegate.